# How to fix 'Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-declare' was not found.eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-declare)'

Tags: typescript, eslint

I am new to eslint and I cannot figure out how to solve this issue. The beginning of my imports is always underlined with a red line. It complains about the definition not being found for the specified rule. I would like to keep the rule in place as it is seems it will be otherwise useful. [image].

For my .eslintrc.js file I have the following rules set up:

`

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        browser: true,
        node: true
    },
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
        'prettier'
    ],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
        project: 'tsconfig.json',
        sourceType: 'module'
    },
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', '@typescript-eslint/tslint'],
    rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/class-name-casing': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility': [
            'off',
            {
                accessibility: 'explicit'
            }
        ],
        '@typescript-eslint/indent': ['error', 'tab'],
        '@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style': [
            'error',
            {
                multiline: {
                    delimiter: 'semi',
                    requireLast: true
                },
                singleline: {
                    delimiter: 'semi',
                    requireLast: false
                }
            }
        ],
        '@typescript-eslint/member-ordering': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-misused-new': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-declare': ['error', { functions: true, classes: true, variables: true }],
        '@typescript-eslint/prefer-function-type': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/quotes': ['error', 'single'],
        '@typescript-eslint/semi': ['error', 'always'],
        '@typescript-eslint/type-annotation-spacing': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/unified-signatures': 'error',
        'arrow-body-style': 'error',
        camelcase: 'off',
        'capitalized-comments': 'error',
        'constructor-super': 'error',
        curly: 'error',
        'dot-notation': 'off',
        'eol-last': 'error',
        eqeqeq: ['error', 'smart'],
        'guard-for-in': 'error',
        'id-blacklist': 'off',
        'id-match': 'off',
        'import/no-deprecated': 'warn',
        'max-classes-per-file': ['error', 1],
        'max-len': [
            'error',
            {
                code: 140
            }
        ],
        'no-bitwise': 'error',
        'no-caller': 'error',
        'no-console': [
            'error',
            {
                allow: [
                    'log',
                    'warn',
                    'dir',
                    'timeLog',
                    'assert',
                    'clear',
                    'count',
                    'countReset',
                    'group',
                    'groupEnd',
                    'table',
                    'dirxml',
                    'error',
                    'groupCollapsed',
                    'Console',
                    'profile',
                    'profileEnd',
                    'timeStamp',
                    'context'
                ]
            }
        ],
        'no-debugger': 'error',
        'no-empty': 'off',
        'no-eval': 'error',
        'no-fallthrough': 'error',
        'no-new-wrappers': 'error',
        'no-shadow': [
            'error',
            {
                hoist: 'all'
            }
        ],
        'no-throw-literal': 'error',
        'no-trailing-spaces': 'error',
        'no-undef-init': 'error',
        'no-underscore-dangle': 'off',
        'no-unused-expressions': 'error',
        'no-unused-labels': 'error',
        'no-var': 'error',
        'prefer-const': 'error',
        radix: 'error',
        'spaced-comment': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/tslint/config': [
            'error',
            {
                rules: {
                    'component-class-suffix': [true, 'Component', 'View', 'Routing'],
                    'contextual-lifecycle': true,
                    'directive-class-suffix': true,
                    'import-blacklist': [true, 'rxjs/Rx'],
                    'import-spacing': true,
                    'no-host-metadata-property': true,
                    'no-input-rename': true,
                    'no-inputs-metadata-property': true,
                    'no-output-on-prefix': true,
                    'no-output-rename': true,
                    'no-outputs-metadata-property': true,
                    'no-redundant-jsdoc': true,
                    'one-line': [true, 'check-open-brace', 'check-catch', 'check-else', 'check-whitespace'],
                    'template-banana-in-box': true,
                    'template-no-negated-async': true,
                    'use-component-view-encapsulation': true,
                    'use-lifecycle-interface': true,
                    'use-pipe-decorator': true,
                    'use-pipe-transform-interface': true,
                    'no-unused-vars': ['error', { vars: 'all', args: 'after-used', ignoreRestSiblings: false }],
                    whitespace: [true, 'check-branch', 'check-decl', 'check-operator', 'check-separator', 'check-type']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

`
```

Any idea how to fix this other than removing the rule?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-redeclare' was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64740337/definition-for-rule-typescript-eslint-no-redeclare-was-not-found)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well according to this [page](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-use-before-declare/), this rule is discouraged as modern TypeScript does not use it and is slow to compute. So you should remove the rule.

If however you still want to keep using it, you can try something like `{
  "no-use-before-define": ["error", { "variables": false }]
}`

You can read more about this [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define#options)

Comment: Where does it say so in the link you sent? I read it but didn’t not see references discouraging it’s use with typescript.

Comment: I am sorry, I had provided same link in both the places. I have edited the answer and **page** is now pointing to the proper link. It says that -  "This rule is primarily useful when using the var keyword since the compiler will automatically detect if a block-scoped let and const variable is used before declaration. Since most modern TypeScript doesn’t use var, this rule is generally discouraged and is kept around for legacy purposes. It is slow to compute, is not enabled in the built-in configuration presets, and should not be used to inform TSLint design decisions."

Answer (score 13):

Restart your `Visual Studio Code`.
It may eliminate this error.
Me and [this dev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65495694/11892490) did the same thing.

Comment: Instead of posting an answer which merely links to another answer, please instead [flag the question](/help/privileges/flag-posts) as a duplicate.

Answer (score 10):

For those who googled here, if you encounter some issue with `@typescript-eslint/**` rule not found issue, most likely is because you are using an outdated package.

Here I am using `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` as an example. It may not be your direct dependency, use `npm ls @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` to find out the exact version you are using. And try to update it to latest.

Comment: This was exactly my issue I've been struggling with for a while - although the package I use to store shared ESLint configs has `eslint-plugin` at `4.6`, the application I installed that package into has `eslint-plugin` at `2.33` and that one was being used instead, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

Visual studio usually starts giving this warning after a dependency update.

Using <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>  + <kbd>P</kbd> and running `Restart Extension Host` from there solved the issue for me.

Comment: Finally! Thanks. All the other answers did nothing for me. Just restarting VSCode did the job

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I upgraded from `@typescript-eslint` 5 to 6

just adding `"plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"` to my eslintrc worked for me

```
      "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
```