# Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-redeclare' was not found

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

In all my `.ts` or `.tsx` files I have this warning on the first character in the file like in the screenshot below:

[image]

I'm using a standard CRA setup. Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^8.0.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.3",
    "i18next": "^19.8.3",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.0.1",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "^3.2.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-firebaseui": "^4.1.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.7.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.0",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.9.0",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.3.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "yup": "^0.29.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.4.10",
    "@types/firebase": "^3.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.56",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.6",
    "@types/react-select": "^3.0.23",
    "@types/react-syntax-highlighter": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.9",
    "cypress": "^5.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.2",
    "i18next-parser": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "test": "react-scripts test --runInBand",
    "extract": "i18next --config i18next-parser.config.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

and my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "types": ["cypress"],
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: DId you ever get that fixed? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Also running into this now. Hello future visitors attempting to upgrade to CRA v4

Comment: For me, the problem simply went away... I honestly don't know what I've done, maybe a fix in some library simple cam through.

Answer (score 54):

I had recently updated my dependencies on my project when I saw this same error. A simple restart of Visual Code appears to have eliminated the error.

Comment: Thanks, this was my exact scenario, restarting VS Code was the solution

Comment: This helped, thanks. `shift + command + p` then restart extension host worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. The way I fixed it was to (a) update the parser and (b) create the file eslintrc.json that uses this last version.

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.7.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.7.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.0.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
```

And the eslintrc.json is like:

```
module.exports = {
  "env": {
      "es2020": true,
      "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "airbnb",
    "eslint:recommended",
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 11,
      "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "prettier",
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
    "no-console": ["error"]
  }
};
```

Comment: That's an `eslintrc.js` file, not `.json`. In a json file, you would omit the `module.exports`.

Comment: Anyway, that `plugins` section is what I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

When updating dependencies check your `resolutions` too. I got this when updating `react-scripts` to v4 while having fixed ts eslint versions due to [this issue](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1746):

```
"resolutions": {
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "2.23.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "2.23.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree": "2.23.0"
},
```

Comment: This works for me and restarting VS code is required.

Answer (score 2):

> I had recently updated my dependencies on my project when I saw this same error. A simple restart of Visual Code appears to have eliminated the error.

I tried the other various solutions provided here, but none worked. Since I had been updating packages (`yarn upgrade-interactive --latest`), I suppose it's possible that my `node_modules` was not *ideal*. After I cleared the cache and reinstalled `node_modules`, the error went away.

```
npx lerna clean -y && yarn cache clean && yarn install
```

Or if you aren't in a lerna (mono) repo, just do:

```
rm -rf node_modules && yarn cache clean && yarn install
```

Since the errors were only appearing in vscode (and not when running lint), I restarted vscode and the errors went away.

Comment: A simple restart worked for me.  I also was upgrading my packages but didn't invoke any of the cache cleaning as the restart worked.

Comment: Perfect thanks, have ran into it a couple of times now, so I added a script in root package `"clean": "npx lerna clean -y && yarn install"`

Answer (score 1):

I am using a project that has Yarn workspaces. It turns out two projects were using `eslint-config-react-app` and one was using an older version without this rule. Unfortunately that was the version that was running.

To troubleshoot with Yarn, use `yarn why eslint-config-react-app`. This will tell you why the package was installed and what versions.

I fixed my issue by adding a [Yarn resolution](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) in the top-level package.json file:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "eslint-config-react-app": "6.0.0"
  },
```

(You should pin the version to whatever version that CRA is using).

Answer (score 1):

If nothing works for you, as for me, this might be helpful for you too.

If you use **create-react-app**, add this **"rules"** in **package.json**

```json
 "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "rules": {
      "@typescript-eslint/no-redeclare": "off",
      "no-redeclare": "off"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by adding the following rules to Eslint config that I found on the typescript-eslint repository.

```js
{
  // note you must disable the base rule as it can report incorrect errors
  "no-redeclare": "off",
  "@typescript-eslint/no-redeclare": ["error"]
}
```

> make sure to restart the typescript server!