# Can't resolve 'react-image-video-lightbox'

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, importerror

This is my first question on StackOverflow. So might miss out on detailing, so please correct me if needed.

I am facing an issue with one of my imports in reactJs. The package **react-image-video-lightbox**.
I installed the package with "npm i react-image-video-lightbox" and also checked the node_modules, the package is present in node_modules as well.

But for some reason, when i run npm start it is still not able to locate the package.

Project Directory
[image: My directory structure]

Node Modules (The highlighted one)
[image: Package in node_module]

The directory structure of react-image-video-lightbox
[image: This is how the package looks]

The error

[image: Error for the package]

The way I am importing
[image: Importing the package, look at the highlighted one.]

Also, shows up in package suggestion
[image: It is also showing up in module suggestion]

I am not sure what i am doing wrong. My node version is 12.22, npm is 6.14 and reactjs version is ^16.13.

Any help and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [Can you check if this solution solves your issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69130002/8417783)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't resolve 'react-image-video-lightbox'
try to execute these commands
[

- yarn cache clean
- yarn upgrade
- yarn remove react-image-video-lightbox
- yarn add react-image-video-lightbox

]

For install recent version

Comment: There is no need to upgrade

Comment: Your answer is correct. I was already doing the same steps but was not working.
However, I had to restart my terminal, not sure why but that solved the problem.

Comment: Adding another comment as I am unable to edit the previous one.
Instead of yarn, i was using npm.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to run this command in terminal

> npm config set legacy-peer-deps true

and then try install package it should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the support.

I figured out the issue. It was a cache issue. Even though I cleared the cache, it was still not working.

So I used the below commands.

- npm cache clean
- npm remove react-image-video-lightbox
- npm add react-image-video-lightbox

However, it was still not working. So I restarted my terminal. And boom! then it worked!

Weird behavior!